# What is "X" file in startup tab of task manager?

Tags: file, startup, taskmanager

[My taskmanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhGfC.png)

Hello ! I'd like to know if someone else also has this "file" and can explain what is it. I can't access to his path :/... Maybe it's just a temporary file.
Thank you by advance !
Lotcelan.

Comment: Looks sketchy AF, but this site is for programming questions. This *may* be appropriate on Super User, but they'll probably just say there's no way for them to know without more information. I think you can right click on it to see path information which might give you a better idea.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More info is available in the [help].